# Create and Copy hyperlink with text/caption to Clipboard with c#

Tags: c#, hyperlink, copy, clipboard, paste

In all sorts of programs you can copy hyperlinks to clipboard and paste them into other applications. E g the ’feedback always welcome’ link at the bottom of this page can be copied and pasted into MS Word. I want to create such a link programmatically, copy it to the Clipboard and then be able to paste it somewhere else.

For example a link with the text ***Stack*** that maps to ***stackoverflow.com***.

I’ve tried all sorts of things with Clipboard.SetData but nothing seems to do the trick.

(I'm working on a Windows form application in VS2010, .NET4.0)

Comment: Can you specify what kind of architecture your application will use? Are you trying to achieve this in Windows Forms, in ASP.NET or in WPF?

Comment: Sorry...VS 2010, .NET 4.0...Win form application (no ASP, WPF)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know the architecture you're working with, but in any case you have just to copy the URL in the Clipboard.

For example, assuming you've got an `HyperLink` control named *myHyperlink* and a `Button` named *copyButton*.

When the user clicks the button you have just to use `Clipboard.SetText(string)` passing to the method the URL Property of *myHyperlink*.

**EDIT:** To show an hyperlink with caption in another program like Word you have to set the text in a HTML way with a particular header.

```
Version:0.9
StartHTML:<<<<<<<1
EndHTML:<<<<<<<2
StartFragment:<<<<<<<3
EndFragment:<<<<<<<4
SourceURL: www.google.it
<html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment-->
<a href="http://programmers.stackexchange.com/">programmers</a></span></span>
<!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
```

This is an example of HTML, let's try to generalize it in C#:

```
private const string html = @"Version:0.9
StartHTML:<<<<<<<1
EndHTML:<<<<<<<2
StartFragment:<<<<<<<3
EndFragment:<<<<<<<4
SourceURL: {0}
<html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment-->
<a href='{0}'>{1}</a>
<!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>";
```

And then use it as follows:

```
string link = String.Format(html, "http://www.google.it", "Google");
Clipboard.SetText(link, TextDataFormat.Html);
```

Comment: I’m afraid this is not what I’m looking for. Copy an arbitrary link on this page and paste it into e g Word. Take the one to the right, under ‘Related’: ‘Paste text from Clipboard using button’. When I paste that into Word it will display as ‘Paste text from Clipboard using button’. When you click it you will be brought to wherever the underlying URL is pointing. The kind of object used for this must be containing both some caption (the displayed text) and an URL, thus Clipboard.setText(...) is not sufficient.

Comment: I'm sorry, I hadn't understood well the question. What you copy from the browser is essentially Html, Word recognize it and displays the links. Try this: `Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);`. Then in your program parse the Html and display it the way you want.

Comment: I was most likely somewhat vague, sorry for this. However, the Clipboard.GetText(...) is of no interest to me. I may paste the clipboard content in just any program (by pressing CTRL + V), like Word, Excel etc. I will not be in control of how the clipboard content is retrieved. The question is how to fill the Clipboard (from code) so that this can be achieved. Let’s say I want the word ‘go’ to map to ‘google.com’. How do I push that into the clipboard so that when pasted into Word, Word understands that it should display a hyperlink with the text ‘go’ that maps to ‘google.com’?

Comment: Indeed it does. Your suggested solution works perfect. Thanks…

Comment: Works great in Outlook 2013 for me!

Comment: AMAZING! thanks so much!
It perfectly works in Visual Studio 2012, just don't forgett to reference the "System.Windows.Forms" or you will not be abel to use the Clipboard function.

Answer (score 1):

In the case somebody has the same problem as me:
The suggested solution for "hyperlink with caption in another program like Word" does not work totally like copying a hyperlink, because if you past in a program, which does not support hyperlinks, you past nothing. If you would [manualy](http://www.google.com) copy a hyperlink, it would past the caption.

I achieved this by additionally adding the caption string to the clipboard to the solution by @as-cii 
(it doesn't seem perfect so let me know, if you know a better solution)

```
private const string html = @"Version:0.9
StartHTML:<<<<<<<1
EndHTML:<<<<<<<2
StartFragment:<<<<<<<3
EndFragment:<<<<<<<4
SourceURL: {0}
<html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment-->
<a href='{0}'>{1}</a>
<!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>";
```

```
string link = String.Format(html, "http://www.google.com", "Google");
DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
dataObject.SetText(link, TextDataFormat.Html);
dataObject.SetText("Google");
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject, true);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I implemented it in JavaScript with:
`...`
`el.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {event.clipboardData.setData('text/html', 'Version:0.9...'); event.clipboardData.setData('text', 'Simple text version');}`
I don't see anything wrong with that. In fact, to me, it seems pretty similar to combining plaintext and html version in emails.

Answer (score 1):

https://theartofdev.com/2014/06/12/setting-htmltext-to-clipboard-revisited/ worked best for me.

Handles the problem described by @NellyFlo, plus pastes in Skype for Business.

In short:

- include [ClipboardHelper.cs](https://gist.github.com/ArthurHub/10729205)
- set the clipboard with 
  `var text = "Google";
  var link = "http://www.google.com";
  ClipboardHelper.CopyToClipboard("\<a href=\"{link}\">{text}</a>", text);`